# Connecting to a MediaTek smartwatch

Tags: fedora, usb, dmesg

I am trying to connect into a chinese "Garrett GT13" smartwatch. It is a MediaTek-powered smartwatch, with the processor being MT2502.
My distro is Fedora 36, the Linux kernel version being `5.19.6-200.fc36.x86_64`.
The dmesg command returns the following output:

```
[ 5376.183879] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 5376.183887] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 5376.187890] option 2-1.2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 5376.188541] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 5376.189479] cdc_acm: probe of 2-1.2:1.1 failed with error -16
[ 5379.056459] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 8
[ 5379.057039] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 5379.057062] option 2-1.2:1.0: device disconnected
```

Would there be any way for me to connect/SSH into the smartwatch using /dev/ttyUSB0 ?

Kind regards.